# C++ | Exception thrown...Access violation reading location ERROR

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement Newton physics inside of a little project I'm working on. I wrote a parser to implement it inside of Half-Life 1.

When I try to use it in a map, it throws an Access violation error. Its' location is 0xFFFFFFF0.

When I tried to use Debug in Visual Studio 2015 it pointed me to here.

```
bmodels[ modelNum ] =   NewtonCreateConvexHull( m_pWorld, numVerts, ( float* )&verts[ 0 ][ 0 ], 12, NULL );
```

So I'm at a loss. The full function can be found here on http://pastebin.com/W6NAs2hM.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a really quick at your code and based off the error you described it looks like you are accessing your array out of bounds.

You start your initial for loop with an index of 1 , ie, modelNum = 1

```
for( int modelNum = 1; modelNum < m_iNumModels; modelNum++ )
```

and then in the line

```
bmodels[ modelNum ] =   NewtonCreateConvexHull( m_pWorld, numVerts, ( float* )&verts[ 0 ][ 0 ], 12, NULL );
```

you try to access `bmodels[1]`, but really it should be `bmodels[0]` since 0 is always the first index of an array.